# How to know when ajax started and finished in $.post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In jquery, there are `.ajaxComplete()`, .`ajaxStart()` events so you can display a loading image until request is complete. I use $.post and want to know if there are same events with `$.post` or how can I display loading image with `$.post` until request is complete when I click a button?

Thank you...

Comment: Have you checked the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation at jQuery?

Comment: Of course, but I could not find about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ajaxStart** & **ajaxComplete** are global handlers that triggered each time a ajax request has been made, which means u don't need to change your post request, just add the following code:

```
$('.log').ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).append('<h1>ajax start.</h1>');
});

$(".log").ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(this).append("<h1>ajax complete.</h1>");
});
```

and html which can be used to show/hide an loader also:

```
<div class="log">      
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**$.post()** has a success callback, I believe.So start displaying your loading img at click or whatever starts your ajax call, and hide it within success callback.

Provided that you fired the appearance of your overlay/spinner at the same time with ajax call, this hides it after it finished:

```
   $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      $('#spinner').hide();
   });
```

You can also use `remove()` instead of `hide()`